# Angular 2 - Apply a function to one object in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have an array of "any" type with multiple objects inside of it, as so:

```
//List of posts (array)
this.posts = [

       //First Post (object)
       {
            userFirst: 'Teyah',
            userLast: 'Tharpe',
            postText: 'Good morning, everyone! Have a good day. :)',

            //First Post's comments (array)
            comments: [
                //First Comment (object)
                {
                    cFirstName: 'Jalen',
                    cLastName: 'Tharpe',
                    theirComment: 'Thank you'
                },

                //Second Comment (object)
                {
                    cFirstName: 'Gerald',
                    cLastName: 'Matthews',
                    theirComment: 'Thank you! You do the same.'
                }
            ]
        },

        //Second Post (object)
        {
            userFirst: 'Jordan',
            userLast: 'Gibson',
            postText: 'What is the move for today?',
            comments: [
                {
                    cFirstName: 'Joshua',
                    cLastName: 'Stewart',
                    theirComment: 'Party at my house!!!'
                }
            ]
        }

    ];
```

As you can see, I have an array of posts, which contains objects, and within the post objects, I have a list of comments. I am trying to apply a `comment()`function, to only one of the objects. Say, `posts[0]`. Can someone let me know if this is within scope for Angular 2? If so, please help.

If more code/information is needed, please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: what do you want to do?

Comment: What do you mean by "apply a comment() function"?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is within the scope of Angular, as it is in the scope of javascript! The detailed answer to your question depends on exactly what you want to do with your `comment()` function. I will try to anticipate a couple of things you might like to do.

1. Add a new comment to a certain post's comment array

   ```
   addComment(post, comment) {
     post.comments.push(comment);
   }
   ```
2. Find a post based on its index and add a comment

   ```
   addCommentUsingIndex(postIndex, comment) {
     this.posts[postIndex].comments.push(comment);
   }
   ```
3. Extract the number of comments for a given post

   ```
   countComments(postIndex) {
     return this.posts[postIndex].comments.length;
   }
   ```
4. get an array of the full names of each commenter of a certain post

   ```
   transformComments(postIndex) {
     return this.posts[postIndex].comments.map(comment => {
       return comment.cFirstName + ' ' + comment.cLastName
     });
   }
   ```

Does that roughly cover your requirements?